# fit the list of <option> tags within a Bootstrap card perfectly

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, html-select

I am using **Angular** with **Bootstrap 4.0** and want to use `<select>` and `<option>`, `<optgroup>` within `card`

The code for the `component.html` is here:

```
<div class="container">
    <h4> Property Explorer</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Available Properties</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <label for="typeahead-template"><span>Search</span></label>
                    <input id="typeahead-template" type="text" class="form-control">

                    <select size="10" class="custom-select mr-4" style="height: auto">
                        <optgroup label="Properties">
                            <option *ngFor="let eachVal of dataResults"
                                    (click)="getPropValues(eachVal)">
                                {{eachVal.translatedProperty}}
                            </option>
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="References">
                            <option *ngFor="let eachVal of objResults"
                                    (click)="getReferenceValues(eachVal)"
                            >
                                {{eachVal.translatedProperty}}</option>
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### Current Output

when the data is loaded for the `*ngFor` the card with looks as following:
[image: Current Output]

### Expectation

Is there a better way to align the `input` and `select` tags within the card?

I had to use `style="height:auto"` to improve the height of the `select` else I wasn't able to see the `select` tag clearly.

Comment: Have you tried adding the bootstrap class `.form-control` to the `<select>` element?

Comment: Just beat me to it.

Comment: @cale_b you can write that as an answer and perhaps if you have some tricks up your sleeve for making it look better I can accept it as an answer.

Comment: I've posted an answer, however - to help with the "look better" part  I'd need to know - what do you mean by "align the input and select tags"?  The input is aligned - is there something else you're looking for? Spacing, padding, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the bootstrap class [form-control](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#form-controls) on the select will apply Bootstrap's pretty awesome CSS to make it look and feel correct within the Bootstrap card

NOTE: I've also added some `<div class="form-group">`  containers around the inputs / selects, to add the desired spacing / padding (`form-group` is another Bootstrap class designed to do just this):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h4> Property Explorer</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Available Properties</div>
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="typeahead-template"><span>Search</span></label>
            <input id="typeahead-template" type="text" class="form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">

            <select size="10" class="form-control mr-4">
              <optgroup label="Properties">
                <option>An Option</option>
                <option>An Option</option>
                <option>An Option</option>
                <option>An Option</option>
                <option>An Option</option>
              </optgroup>
              <optgroup label="References">
                <option>An Option</option>
                <option>An Option</option>
                <option>An Option</option>
                <option>An Option</option>
                <option>An Option</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that you've also used the [custom-select](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#custom-forms) which actually feels like *not* what you were looking for, so I've removed it.

Comment: I tried the code, I found something strange. My `select` fits completely in the card whileas yours has some padding around. Here is the [image](https://imgur.com/a/EbwPwWC) which I render

Comment: That's very hard to troubleshoot, as we don't know - do you have OTHER styles being applied? And, what we really need to know is your _Rendered HTML_ - you've shown the Angular template, but the actual HTML that is generated / output would be much more helpful.  Lastly, I've added a bit of markup to the answer, to leverage `<div class="form-group">` to help add some of the spacing you are looking for.

Comment: Figured it out I have other components that use `card-block` instead of `card-body` and it works perfect. Thanks